# Calculating date difference in SQL query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need to calculate date difference using flowing query but it does not work.  Please advise.

```
SELECT ID, VoucherNo, DateRec, ProductID, Description, ClaimantCo, ClaimantName, City, Phone, DateReturn, ReqJob, WSIns, Remarks, Status, Part1, Part2, Part3, Part4, OtherWSCharges, FDCharges, P1Charges, P2Charges, P3Charges, P4Charges, DateJobBegun, DateJobDone, WSRemarks, TotChargesFromWS, DeliveryStatus, DateDelivered 
FROM tblClaims 
WHERE DateDiff(dd, DateReturn, GETDATE()) =3
```

My purpose is to get records for which three days are left to DateRetun, comparing to today's date.

Thanks

Comment: DateReturn datatype is DateTime?

Comment: Your error "Failed to get schema" does not appear to be related to the DateDiff condition. Do you get the same error if you run the query in SSMS?

Comment: The DateReturn is DateTime.  If I take off the DateDiff portion, there is not error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've just got the datediff parameters the wrong way round - if you're looking for three days in the future you want to say:

```
datediff(dd, getdate(), DateReturn) = 3
```

Comment: Changed but same error:  Failed to get schema for select command

Comment: You won't get schema error messages if you're running the query in SQL Management Studio. Prove the query works there and then if when you're consuming the query you get a schema error you then need to look at how you're specifying the schema of the results

Answer (score 0):

What is DateReturn datatype? I have tested as follow. If DateReturn datatype is DateTime, it should work.

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = dateadd(day,-3, getdate())

select datediff(dd,@dt, getdate())
```

result is 3

Comment: But how to use it with where clause

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (if DateReturn is a datetime):

```
SELECT 
    DateReturn 
FROM 
    tblClaims 
WHERE 
    tblClaims.DateReturn BETWEEN GETDATE()-3 AND GETDATE()
```